# OpenGL not rendering triangle from vertex buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

My program did not render any objects and showed a blank screen. I have checked for any openGL errors and haven't been able to find any.

Header file (Display.h):

```
#include "glew.h"
#include "glfw3.h"
#include <iostream>
class Display
{
    
public:
    Display() {
        glfwInit();

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE); 
        if (window == nullptr)
        {
            window = glfwCreateWindow(649, 489, "GL_Lib", NULL, NULL);
        }
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); 
        glewInit(); 
    };
    static GLFWwindow* window;

    void Create_Buffer(float f, float s, float t, float forth, float fifth, float sixth, unsigned int* ptr) {
        float positions[6] = { f,s,t,forth,fifth,sixth };
        glGenBuffers(1, ptr);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *ptr); 
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), 0);
        return;
    }
    static unsigned int Create_Shader(const std::string& VertexShader, const std::string FragmentShader) {
        unsigned int program = glCreateProgram(); 
        unsigned int vs = Compile_Shader(VertexShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        unsigned int fs = Compile_Shader(FragmentShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glAttachShader(program, vs);
        glAttachShader(program, fs);
        glLinkProgram(program);
        glValidateProgram(program);
        int status;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &status);  
        std::cout << status;
        glDeleteShader(vs);
        glDeleteShader(fs); 

        return program; 
    }
    static unsigned int Compile_Shader(const std::string& source, unsigned int type)
    {
        unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
        const char* src = source.c_str(); 

        glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(id);
        //TODO: Error Handling
        return id;
    }

    static void GLCheckError() {
        while (GLenum error = glGetError())
        {
            std::cout << "Error (" << error << ")" << std::endl;
        }

    }
    static void GLClearError()
    {
        while(glGetError != GL_NO_ERROR); 
    }

};
```

Cpp file (Main.cpp):

```
#pragma once
#include "glew.h"
#include "glfw3.h"
#include "Display.h"
#include <iostream>



int main()
{ 
   
    
    Display* dis = new Display();
    unsigned int* buffer = new unsigned int;
    dis->Create_Buffer(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, buffer);


    std::string vertexShader = 
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "gl_Position = position;\n"
        "}\n";

    std::string fragmentShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";

    unsigned int shader = Display::Create_Shader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(Display::window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shader);
        // draw points 0-3 from the currently bound VAO with current in-use shader
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(Display::window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();


        Display::GLCheckError();
    }


    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I also have a Display.cpp file but this is just to resolve the GLFW window symbol.

Comment: You do not create a core profile. You create a compatibility profile. (`GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE`)

Comment: The coordinates do not define a triangle, but a straight line: `-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f` (the y-coordinate is always -0.5f). SO no triangle primitive is rendered.

Comment: I thought I created both in the constructor, did I make a mistake?

Comment: You cannot create both. `glfwWindowHint` just sets a parameter. The context is created when `glfwCreateWindow` is called. You must use a compatibility profile.

Comment: You are correct, I did create a straight line, now it works as intended, thank you

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I have now deleted the line that declares the core profile

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates do not define a triangle, but a straight line. For this reason, no triangle primitive is rendered. Change the coordinates:

<s>`dis->Create_Buffer(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, buffer);`</s>

```cpp
dis->Create_Buffer(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, buffer);
```